# How to change a javascript variable with HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, google-chrome-extension, global-variables

I am making a chrome extension which adds icons to certain URLs, so I would like to make a slider to adjust the size of the icon in the `popup.html`.

The HTML of the slider looks like this:

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
   <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="2" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

But for the slider to work, it needs some javascript code.

In the javascript file, I made a variable called `size`. I need the javascript to change the `size` variable according to the position of the slider.

```js
var size = "/images/icon16.png";
var imageURL = "chrome-extension://" + chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id") + size;
```

So I am thinking of a script that checks for `myRange`, and if it is `1`,  `2`, or `3`, it sets `size` to corresponding string:

1. `"/images/icon16.png"`
2. `"/images/icon48.png"`
3. `"/images/icon128.png"`

The catch is that I don't know how to implement this in my code, so any help or explanation would mean the world to me ...

Answer (score 0):

You could save your strings in an array:

```js
var myPaths = [
  "/images/icon16.png",
  "/images/icon48.png",
  "/images/icon128.png"
]
```

And access your slider input like this:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
```

so that `slider.value` will be the value of the `input`.

You could listen out for the `change` event on the slider, and then set your `size` variable accordingly.

Full code:

```js
var myPaths = [
  "/images/icon16.png",
  "/images/icon48.png",
  "/images/icon128.png"
];

var size = "/images/icon16.png";
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");

slider.addEventListener("change", updateSize);

function updateSize() {
  size = myPaths[slider.value - 1];
}
```

Comment: why make two variables instead make this "document.getElementById("myRange").value;" ??

Comment: @Smartye I've edited my answer and removed the need for the `sliderValue` variable, `slider.value` can simply be used instead. However, I wouldn't use `document.getElementById("myRange").value`, because then the element has to be loaded from the DOM each time that the value changes. Storing it in the `slider` variable means that this only has to be done once, when the variable is first set.

Answer (score 0):

In short: `document.getElementById("myRange").value;`.

You can read more about sliders and getting the value of the slider [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp). If you want to get the value every time the slider is utilised:

```js
document.getElementById("myRange").addEventListener("input", (evt) => {
  console.log(evt.target.value);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Attach an `onchange` event listener to the `input` tag.
2. Declare `enum` as follows:

```js
let enum = {
  1: "/images/icon16.png",
  2: "/images/icon48.png",
  3: "/images/icon128.png"
}
```

3. Write something like this in the callback:

```js
var size,
    imageURL;

let enum = {
  1: "/images/icon16.png",
  2: "/images/icon48.png",
  3: "/images/icon128.png"
} 

let inputrange = document.querySelector('input[type=range]');

inputrange.addEventListner("change", function() {
  size = enum[inputrange.value];
  imageURL = `chrome-extension://${chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id") + size}` ;
}) ;
```

Comment: Previously I was expecting you to add eventlistners and attach that callback to function but I did that now